# Скрытый readonly (не сохраняет файлы после перезагрузки)

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, ssd, raspbian

Может тут много воды, но мне кажется что это важно.

В начале феврале обнаружил что после перезапуска системы (raspbian 10) файлы откатились назад. В этот момент файлы ещё писались, иногда. RPi4 2GB часто стал вырубаться и я начал смотреть лог. Там обнаружил сильную активность в стороне брутфорса (китай, снг, америка) и поиска прокси (тут я не понял, зачем один и тот ip пытается пробиться в проксирование). Через пару дней сервер вообще перестал запускаться и пришлось ставить новую систему (raspbian 11), тут возможно я сам поломал её, когда пк зависал, то пришлось вырубать питание. Файлы сохранял через ext2mgr и также потом их закидывал обратно (это легче чем скопировать большие конфиги, которые редактируются через root). Пару дней радовался, но через неделю ситуация повторилась. Всё тот же readonly не сохраняет файлы, но это не происходило каждый раз. Прошло ещё пару недель и теперь никакие файлы не сохраняет (даже boot или обновление), хотя до этого сохранял "избранные". Тут начал гуглить что можно предпринять и начал с монтирования, которое не имеет общего с readonly (и оно не так проявляется), обновил систему, выключил readonly через rpi-tools, проверил ssd на ошибки, была полу ошибка 161 Unknown Block(?) PreFail, а потом перезапустил и всё что установил сбросилось, с тех пор ни разу нормально ничего не работало.

RPi используется (использовалась месяцев 9) как web-server. SSD 128gb kingspec воткнут в USB2.0 (на USB3.0 были отсоединения накопителя). Питание через дорогой адаптер (там точно 15w есть, проверено). Не помню в какой момент времени, скорее после переустановки, но при редактировании файлов через винду они сохранялись через раз. В начале при таком readonly режиме логи сохранялись, а потом перестали. В syslog есть инфа о запусках 15 и 17 марта, хотя в эти времена и по 20 был не один перезапуск в день, но в логах один и дальше пусто, кроме null на десять тысяч раз в одной строке и строк из конфигов или модулей (не полный вывод, но часть имеется и всегда разная).

UPD: ошибка перестала быть после нескольких перестановок из адаптеров sata3, но погуглил и нашёл точно такие же симптомы и ответы были об исчерпании ресурсов. Мои ресурсы чтения 231GB, запись 1206GB, Nand запись ~1340GB, включения 394, время работы 6540 ч (272.5 дня).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подходящая проблема под мою ситуацию это исчерпание ресурса памяти, но 1.3 TB это очень мало, даже для 120GB, поэтому есть предположение что это контроллер уходить в readonly режим и для проверки этого я перепрошил его. На usbdev нашёл SMI Mass Production Tool под мой контроллер и мою память (в начале не определялась, но после тыков в приложении начало всё определяться в smi_flash_id_ata) SM2258XT(AD)_SNK-BiCS4_PKGT1216A_FWT0910A0, но вся информация о SMART сбросилась.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).